# Shifting in FFT

Tags: matlab, fft

**Input image**

[image]

**Listing-1**

```
i = imread('Untitled.png');
i = rgb2gray(i);
F = fft2(i);
%%%F = fftshift(F);
F = abs(F);
F = log(F+1); 
F = mat2gray(F); 
imshow(F);
```

**Output**

[image]

.

**Listing-2**

```
i = imread('Untitled.png');
i = rgb2gray(i);
F = fft2(i);
F = fftshift(F);
F = abs(F);
F = log(F+1); 
F = mat2gray(F); 
imshow(F);
```

**Output**

[image]

Seeing the the above two outputs, can you answer the following questions,

1. Why does the FFT of an image produce such an spectrum where zero frequencies are at the corner of the image?
2. Why is that a problem (or, is that)?
3. Why does the shifting operation fixes that phenomenon?

Comment: The two listings seem to be identical?

Comment: @Florian, thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some answers:

1. Why does the FFT of an image produce such an spectrum where zero
   frequencies are at the corner of the image?

The `fft` is a fast implementation of the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT). In 1-D, the DFT is defined as X[m] = \sum_n x[n] exp(j 2 pi (m-1)(n-1)/N). Therefore, clearly, the first element of the transform corresponds to the frequency zero. This is similar in 2-D, where the first row/column carries the zero frequency.

2. Why is that a problem (or, is that)?

It isn't, not at all. It works as intended. It is maybe only a "problem" that we are more used to seeing the zero frequency in the middle since spectrum has some symmetries so we like to look at it in [-Nyquist,Nyquist] instead of [0,2*Nyquist]. Though technically this is no different since it is anyways periodic.

3. Why does the shifting operation fixes that phenomenon?

Since shifting the zero frequency to the middle produces images that are somewhat visually more pleasing, a function to do this job has been made available. It is only intended to be used for display. The documentation of [`fftshift`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html) shows in detail how it works, also in 2-D.